# Would you ever use the [jquery-ui] tag without the [jquery] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

I think that if you were able to use one and not the other then it would okay to not synonymize the [jquery-ui](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui) to [jquery](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jquery).

But it just doesn't seem like we need both of these tags. I think that we should merge or synonymize them to each other.

Pros and cons please?

You use [javascript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and [jquery](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jquery) to create the [jquery-ui](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui), so this is rather redundant, it's kind of like having [wordpress](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) and [wordpress-ui](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-ui).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that tags are useful even if one tag is a subset of another. For example, on Stack Overflow, there is the tag [c#](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%23), but there are also its subsets: [c#-2.0](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%23-2.0), [c#-3.0](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%23-3.0), [c#-4.0](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%23-4.0), [c#-5.0](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%23-5.0). But this does not make such tags useless (for example, I am subscribed to [c#-5.0](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%23-5.0), but not to the other subtags or the supertag).

So, I don't see any reason why the two tags should be synonymized, since they are no synonyms.

Comment: jQuery-ui isn't a version of jQuery, C#-5.0 is a version of C#

Comment: @Malachi Sure, but if I understand your argument, you're saying “jQuery-ui is a subset of jQuery, so it's a useless tag”. I'm saying “C#-5.0 is a subset of C#, but it's also a useful tag, so your argument isn't valid”. When I say “subset” I don't mean “version”, I mean “whenever you use the sub-tag, the super-tag is also valid”.

Comment: your subset (C#-5.0) defines rules in the code,  jquery-ui doesn't define any rules, it's the same code.

Comment: @Malachi AFAIK, [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) is a library built on top of jQuery. So it's not the same code.

Comment: I hear that argument, and will look into it.

Comment: looks like it is a completely different framework.